# Как перезагрузить отображенное изображение?

Tags: jquery, изображения

Изображение на странице показывается так:

```
<img src='path'>
```

Когда страница загружается, на сервер идет запрос, потом изображение магическим образом отображается в браузере (и, вероятно, сохраняется где-то на компе пользователя). Обычно всего этого достаточно.

А если после того, как пользователь увидит картинку, она будут изменена на сервере. Как обновить картинку в браузере без перезагрузки страницы?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery:

```
$("#button").on("click", function(){
    var $img = $("#img");
    $img.attr("src", $img.attr("src").split("?")[0] + "?" + Math.random());       
});
```

Comment: А если в src не будет символа [?]?

Comment: Идею понял, спасибо!

Comment: Если его не будет, елемент с нулевым индексом будет содержать весь src.

Answer (score 0):

Ну, может кому пригодится. Сделал глупо, но работает:

```
var src = $("img").attr('src'); 
$("img").removeAttr('src').attr('src', src);
```

Картинка исправно обновляется.

Comment: Можно простопоменять значение src, не обязательно его удалять)

Comment: Ну, я что б наверняка!